# How do i input data and press buttons in a webbrowser using c#?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2019

when you press the submit button i want the data in the textboxes to be filled into the webbrowser (inside the windows form) and for the login button to be pressed

I could not find the answer anywhere and i want to use this to make something automated

i currently have no code except 
`webBrowser1.Navigate("https://en-gb.facebook.com/");`

currently it doesnt function but i want to find out how to do this in a simple way as i am not that good at c# yet.[image of what it looks like, this will make my question make more sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p78D.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you

Form Load event

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   webBrowser1.Navigate("https://en-gb.facebook.com/");
 }
```

Button Click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // User name
    HtmlElement userElement = (from HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") select element)
        .Where(x=>x.Id == "email").FirstOrDefault();

    if (userElement != null)
    {
        userElement.SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
    }

    // Password
    HtmlElement passwordElement = (from HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") select element)
        .Where(x => x.Id == "pass").FirstOrDefault();

    if (passwordElement != null)
    {
        passwordElement.SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
    }

    // Submit
    HtmlElement submitElement = (from HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") select element)
        .Where(x => x.Id == "u_0_a").FirstOrDefault();
    if (submitElement != null)
    {
        submitElement.InvokeMember("click");
    }    
}
```